# How to factor a very big (10k x 20k) table to enable fast query of a subset of rows and columns in SQL database

Tags: python, sql, django, database, data-structures

I am using Django, and I've factored the big table into small tables. Here is my attempt:

```
class Instance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Feature(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Value(models.Model):
    instance = models.ForeignKey(Instance)
    feature = models.ForeignKey(Feature)
    value = models.FloatField()
```

The most frequent query is to select a small subset of rows (a few hundreds of Instances) and columns (a few dozens of Features) from the big table. I find myself selecting the Features and the samples, then looping around features to get all the corresponding Values, which ends up hitting the database dozens of times, which appears to be very inefficient.

Here is the modified version of the `get` method in my code:

```
def get(self, request):
    cat = self.request.GET.get('category')
    # usually inst_objs is between 300 ~ 2000 long
    inst_objs = Instance.objects.filter(category=cat).all()

    feats = self.request.GET.get('features', '').split(',')
    feat_objs = Feature.objects.filter(name__in=feats).all()

    vals = []
    # usually feat_objs is a few dozens long
    for feat in feat_objs:
        _val = feat.value_set\
                    .filter(instance_id__in=inst_objs)\
                    .values_list('value', flat=True)
        vals.append(list(_val))

    # I have also tried something the following, but it feels even slower
    # value.objects\
    #         .filter(instance_id__in=inst_objs)\
    #         .filter(feature_id__in=feat_objs)\
    #         .all()

    # ...further process with vals before return a response
```

I wonder if there is a common strategy for factoring giant table and enable fast query of a subset of rows and columns

Comment: https://mockaroo.com/ may perhaps help?

Comment: @jarlh, How? I am not looking for mock data.

Comment: Maybe you can provide an example of your current queries or implementation, it's not very clear what is the challenge. Sounds like you can just use `Value.objects.filter(feature__in=features)` filter to select all Values linked to a list of given Features.

Comment: @serg, I've added a code snippet. Sorry, I missed an important column before in Instance, the `category`, which is used for selecting a subset of instances instead of all of them.

Comment: Strange that just the straight forward filter by id gives you performance issues, it can't get any more simpler than that. Have you inspected the generated sql, you are sure it's not something else that causing the slowdown (like maybe you are touching related fields and it generates extra queries)? Might be worth trying to run `explain analyze` on that query and see what's up, if you use postgres the `feature_id` and `instance_id` fields should be indexed.

Comment: I am using MySQL, I thought `feature_id` and `instance_id` should be indexed too by default, right? Sounds you agree this is the reasonable way to design the tables, and you expect the performance to be reasonably fast, too? I thought there might be a better way to design the DB that I am not aware of. I don't have extensive DB design experience myself. I will try `explain analyze` to see what comes up.